# Why doesn't my MSBuild project build incrementally?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a project which generates a class from its XSD definition, then builds it. My problem is that, even though I specify the inputs and outputs of my Xsd target, it still gets executed every time I build the Visual Studio solution. What could be the problem here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" InitialTargets="Xsd" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <!-- snip -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="request.cs">
      <DependentUpon>request.xsd</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="key.snk" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Xsd Include="request.xsd" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Target Name="Xsd" Inputs="@(Xsd)" Outputs="request.cs">
    <Exec Command='"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\xsd.exe" &quot;@(Xsd)&quot; /c /o:..\.. /n:Order.Messaging' />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Xsd target from [InitialTargets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee216359.aspx)

> Initial targets are typically used for error checking.

and add dependency to BeforeBuild Target:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" DependsOnTargets="Xsd" />
```

Comment: Didn't help. Task gets executed on every build anyway.

Comment: Set Verbose in VS Build And Run settings to Diagnostic. Find all calls of Xsd task. You will see something like - one of @(Xsd) inputs is newer than request.cs. Target Xsd can be executed only if that condition satisfied.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently, xsd.exe does not always update the timestamp of the generated file, so I was stuck with an .xsd that was more recent than the .cs. I added a 'touch' task to the Xsd target, and now everything compiles just fine.